# Apply squeeze theorem to a log function

Tags: calculus

How do you show that $\ln(n+1) < n$ for all $n >1$ ?
Uusing the squeeze theorem, I have started by showing that $\frac{1}{n}< \ln n >1$ then how can I proceed?

Comment: What does $a < b > c$ mean?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Let $f(x)=x-\ln(x+1)$ on the interval $[0, \infty)$.

Show that $f'(x) >0$ on $(0, \infty)$ and $f'(0)=0$. What dos this mean? What is $f(0)$?

Comment: I think you meant $f(0)=0$ (not the derivative).

Comment: why is the domain n>1 not n>1.76 where 1/n and ln n meet ?

Comment: @stex One of the reasons is because $\ln(n)$ and $\ln(n+1)$ are two completely different functions. So what $\ln(n)$ does is irrelevant for the problem.... Also, $n$ usually denotes whole numbers, for hole numbers $n>1$ and $n>1.76$ mean exactly the same thing...